# Трансляция видеопотока в интернете.

Tags: видео

**Здравствуйте.**
Очень хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способы прямой трансляции видео в интернете.
Например, на сайте, используя веб-камеру. **Спасибо.**

Comment: @Asen, не забывайте принимать верные ответы.

Comment: Да, точно =)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону [erlyvideo](http://www.linux.org.ru/news/multimedia/5129114)

Comment: А еще лучше вот это: http://www.linux.org.ru/news/multimedia/7041812

Comment: все это, конечно же, прекрасно, но первый вариант платный, а второй только для Linux...

Comment: А Вы сервер под Windows хотите использовать? О_о Скажу сразу, что это плохая идея, с какой стороны не посмотри.

Comment: @Drakmail, чем же?)

Comment: Кривая реализация TCP стека, стоимость (VPS с windows server в 2-5 раз дороже аналогичного с Linux/FreeBSD), потребляет больше ресурсов, требуется антивирус и firewall, требуется GUI для настройки... и это только самые основные недостатки.

Answer (score 2):

Для таких вещей есть специальные программы, называются "серверные приложения", а еще в интернете есть очень много хороших скриптов позволяющих реализовать видеоконференцию дома. Так что Гугл тебе в помощь!И да поможет тебе...

Легко. Попробуй http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/, если понравиться дай знать. 
http://www.oovoo.com а это бесплатный видеочат

Comment: Благодарю. Не могли бы вы поделиться одним из таких скриптов(дать ссылку на изучение)  =)

Comment: http://www.oovoo.com а это бесплатный видеочат

Answer (score 1):

[Реализация простого видеочата на ASP.NET_MVC](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154455/)